# Derivatives of dot product

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $ A\in M_{n}$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \langle Ax,x\rangle$. Find $f'$ and $f''$.

It seems that I need to define $g(x)=Ax$, so $g'(x)=A$

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\langle A(x+h),x+h\rangle-\langle Ax,x\rangle\\
\langle Ax,h\rangle+\langle Ah,x\rangle+\langle Ah,h\rangle.$$

The first two added up seems like $f'$.

But I still have problem to get $f''$. Why define $g$? How to get $f',f''$?

Comment: The naïve (without dwelling too much about the fact that $g'(x) = A$) approach would just be to use the product rule for inner products

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \langle a(x),b(x)\rangle = \left\langle \frac{\mathrm{d} a}{\mathrm{d} x},b(x)\right\rangle+\left\langle a(x),\frac{\mathrm{d} b}{\mathrm{d} x}\right\rangle$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\langle a(x),b(x)\rangle=\langle \frac{\mbox{d}a}{\mbox{d}x},b(x)\rangle+\langle a(x),\frac{\mbox{d}b}{\mbox{d}x}\rangle$$Therefore, 
$$\frac{\mbox{d}^2}{\mbox{d}x^2}\langle a(x),b(x)\rangle=\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\left(\langle \frac{\mbox{d}a}{\mbox{d}x},b(x)\rangle+\langle a(x),\frac{\mbox{d}b}{\mbox{d}x}\rangle\right)=\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\langle \frac{\mbox{d}a}{\mbox{d}x},b(x)\rangle
+\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\langle a(x),\frac{\mbox{d}b}{\mbox{d}x}\rangle\\
=\langle \frac{\mbox{d}^2}{\mbox{d}x^2}a,b(x)\rangle+\langle a,\frac{\mbox{d}^2b}{\mbox{d}x^2}\rangle+2\langle\frac{\mbox{d}a}{\mbox{d}x},\frac{\mbox{d}b}{\mbox{d}x}\rangle$$